# Does a class reinitialize even if I only call one of its methods?

Tags: python, class, methods

Assume I have this class:

```
class myTestClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method(self, arbitrary_value):
        return arbitrary_value
```

And I would only need it's method to take on an arbitrary value, as per this:

```
object = myTestClass()

while n_count > 10:
    print object.method(n_count)
```

Even though I initialize my class before the loop, does it go through the constructor **init** each time it calls 'method'?

Comment: No, it does not. `__init__` is called only when you call your `class` to create that instance.

Comment: It sounds like you ran into some bug in your code that caused you to think Python would do this; you may want to ask a question about that bug.

Comment: Yeah. That's a good point. Explain the issue you are facing.

Comment: @idjaw I see. Does this go against basic OOP's principles? If a method doesn't affect any of the classes' states but is still relevant to that class, could it just be declared as @staticmethod?

Comment: You are confusing terminology here. The `self` *is* your instance being passed through your methods, and that carries the *state* for *that* instance of the class.

Comment: @user2357112 I have to initialize a class that does heavy-load win32api windows names / properties extraction and I was wondering if I could optimize by a bit by not calling the class each time in my While and instead just initialize it before, then call its method inside the loop, as per my question's details and was wondering if it re-initializez the original class even if it's declared outside.

Comment: Based on the code sample you provided, you are not initializing the class inside the loop. You are calling the method on *that* instance each time in that loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating a new object every time, so **init** is not being called more than once (which happens when you run object = myTestClass() )

You are calling the same instance method 10 times.

Comment: @DanVon, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.